# Does $\operatorname{Re}(a+bi)^{n}=\operatorname{Re}(a+bi)^{n+1}$ have at least one solution $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, diophantine-equations, rational-numbers

> Does
> $$\operatorname{Re}((a+bi)^{n})=\operatorname{Re}((a+bi)^{n+1})$$
> have a solution $a,b\in\mathbb{Q},|a|\neq |b|\neq0$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

I was working on [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828348/can-operatornamereabin-be-overlapped-with-a-b-in-mathbbq-fixed-ju), $\operatorname{Re}(a+bi)^m=\operatorname{Re}(a+bi)^n$, then all of the solutions I could find on PC was the case of $n-m=1$ and trivial cases. Is there a reason why many solutions can be found for $n-m=1$, and are there solutions for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w = x + y \, \mathrm i$ for $x,y \in \mathbb Q$ such that $w^n+\overline w^n \neq 0$ and $w^{n+1}+\overline w^{n+1} \neq 0$. Take $$z = w \cdot \frac{w^n+ \overline{w}^n}{w^{n+1}+\overline w^{n+1}}.$$ Then $z$ has rational real and imaginary parts and $$\operatorname{Re}(z^{n+1}) = \operatorname{Re}(z^n).$$
Note that $z$ only depends on the direction of $w$: multiplying $w$ by a non-zero rational factor results in the same $z$.